# 3D Scan interior room and map with equirectangular image

Tags: 3d, 3d-reconstruction

I'm currently looking at the best way for me to scan an interior room using equipment that isn't too expensive.  There's a system out there that takes the picture and scans the room but cost is about $4500.  I came across another device called Structure sensor which produces a 3d model of the room but it was pretty broken up.  Image attached. [image]

I was wondering if I can use this to scan the room and then apply and equirectangular (360 picture to fill in the gaps of any broken area) as a 3d overlay map?  Upon motion such as going forward 5 feet I'd apply another over lay map from the perspective.  The idea would be for the person to move around the room to about 3 different locations and still see around.  It is for a VR type of game.

Answer (score -1):

You can overlay the 360 pictures on the 3D model and first you should get a not bad 3D model. The gap will be ugly if the model is not good. I think the cheap depth camera (about $200) will work not bad. I once create a global consistent model for interior room, here is a link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWMP4YfeNeY&t=29s. Hope it helps.